# read analog value from pin in CCS

Tags: c, embedded

I'm now doing a project in CCS (Code Composer Studio) with the device CC1310.
I think is good to mention that I'm relatively new to CCS.

I have a hard time finding a simple way to read the analog value form the PINS on the board. (similar to Arduino: int x = analogRead(A1) )

Question: How do I store and read analog values from the Pins on the board?

I thankful for all answers

Kind Regards // Troubled Engineering Student

Comment: This sounds more like an arduino question than an IDE question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADC header file should be included in an application as follow

```
#include <ti/drivers/ADC.h>
```

**Operation**

The ADC driver operates as a simplified ADC module with only single channel sampling support. It also operates on blocking only mode which means users have to wait the current sampling finished before starting another sampling. The sampling channel needs to be specified in the **ADC_open()** before calling **ADC_convert()**.

The APIs in this driver serve as an interface to a typical TI-RTOS application. The specific peripheral implementations are responsible to create all the SYS/BIOS specific primitives to allow for thread-safe operation. User can use the ADC driver or the ADCBuf driver that has more features. But both ADC and ADCBuf cannot be used together in an application.

**Opening the driver**

```
ADC_Handle adc;
ADC_Params params;
ADC_Params_init(&params);
adc = ADC_open(Board_ADCCHANNEL_A1, &params);
if (adc == NULL) {
    // ADC_open() failed
    while (1);
}
```

**Converting**

An ADC conversion with a ADC peripheral is started by calling ADC_convert(). The result value is returned by **ADC_convert()** once the conversion is finished

```
int_fast16_t res;
uint_fast16_t adcValue;
res = ADC_convert(adc, &adcValue);
if (res == ADC_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    //use adcValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about digital I/O (on or off) then the term you should research in the MCU's Datasheet and Technical Reference Manual is "GPIO".  If you have a development kit (such as a LaunchPad) then study the GPIO example that is provided with the development kit's SDK.  The SDK probably includes a peripheral driver library that provides a higher level interface to the GPIO peripheral.  If so then you could link your application with the library and use the library API to set/get the GPIO data values.  Or if you want to do it at the lowest level then you'll need to study the memory-mapped interface to the GPIO registers, which is described in the Technical Reference Manual.  For example, the `DIN31_0` register is used to read the GPIO input values.

You can find links to everything I mentioned at http://www.ti.com/product/CC1310